# Authentication Through Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I want a user to login to my Chrome Extension via my normal website's login portal. Specifically, I want to mimic the Grammarly authenticaion flow where a user clicks signin on the Chrome Extension, gets redirected to Grammarly's website, sign ins, then the Chrome extension automatically knows about the user account.

Grammarly probably stores a Cookie when the user logs on the browser that their extension then checks for. Is there a working example of this or guidance on how to set the cookie and then read it from the Chome Extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a [host permission](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/declare_permissions/) for your web site in your extension manifest.

Let the user log in on the web site, and then use the [chrome.cookies](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/cookies/) API to read the cookie.

Now, you can make authenticated requests to your web site, using that cookie.